# Why does promise then without argument still pass on the first value instead of undefined?

Tags: javascript, promise

Consider this code:

```js
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        resolve("OK");
    }, 1000);
});

p.then().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

It outputs "OK".

I don't understand what happens after the first `then` is called. When the first `then` is called it returns `undefined`, which in turn resolves the promise created for this `then` with a value `undefined`.

Yet, for some reason, when the second `then` is called, it is passed "OK" as `data` and subsequently logs it. Where did the "data" come from?

Comment: Looking at the [Promise source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/3.29.45/src/promise.js?autodive=0/#248) for Chromium V8, when a resolve function isn't provided to `then`, a default function is used. That function simply returns whatever value was passed to `then`. In this case `"OK"`.

Comment: *"When the first "then" is called it returns undefined,"*: no, this must be a misunderstanding. `.then()` always returns a promise. You wouldn't be able to chain another `.then()` to it if it had returned undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This "forwarding" of the value is intended behaviour. [Mozilla contributors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) write:

> ### Parameters
>
> `onFulfilled` Optional
>
> A function to asynchronously execute when this promise becomes fulfilled.
> [...]
>
> If it is not a function, it is internally replaced with an identity function (`(x) => x`) which simply passes the fulfillment value forward.

Answer (score -1):

When the first `.then()` is called it actually returns a promise object with the `PromiseResult` as "OK".

[image: Promise object returned from each then call]

When you chain another `.then` with a callback function in the argument that already has access to the "OK" from the previous promise.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).